# Python recursion creates new frame?

Tags: python, recursion, frame

Why does Python create a new frame for each recursive function call in object oriented programming?
I have tried to search for answers on the internet but could not find any specific reason or justification for it. I

Comment: Why it shouldn't ? The frame is created for every function call, why for recursive calls it should be different ?

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, Python could absolutely get away with reusing a stack frame for recursive function calls:

```
def factorial(n, a=1):
    if n == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return factorial(n - 1, n * a)
```

But often every call needs its own stack frame, since there's some state that's unique to each iteration. Let's say that instead of returning the values immediately, we wanted to print them out:

```
def factorial2(n, depth=0):
    if n == 0:
        value = 1
    else:
        value = n * factorial2(n-1, depth+1)

    print(f"Depth: {depth}, Value: {value}")
    return value
```

If we call `factorial2(3)`, then by the time we're at the deepest function call, there are four different `depth` and `value` variables in different stack frames. Python needs to use these values later, so it can't throw away the stack frames in the meantime.

Languages like Scheme still create new stack frames for recursive functions in the general case, but they can avoid it in the special case of tail-call recursion. In the first `factorial`, the recursion is the very last thing that happens before the function returns, so a language like Scheme would know it could re-use the stack frame.

Python could implement this optimization, but Guido van Rossum has opposed it, arguing that it would make debugging harder and encourage non-Pythonic code. You can read these blog articles for his full thought process:

- http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html
- http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2009/04/final-words-on-tail-calls.html

Comment: `return n * factorial(n-1)` isn't tail-recursive. The multiplication is in tail position, not the recursive call.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I edited this to use a proper tail-recursive example.